# Не запускается mysql на mamp pro

Tags: mysql

Привет парни, столкнулся с проблемой не запускается mysql на mamp pro 4.2 , вот лог ошибок

```
2018-03-06 12:48:53 66447 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-03-06 12:48:53 66447 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 49463
2018-03-06 12:48:53 66447 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2018-03-06 12:48:53 66447 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2018-03-06 12:48:53 66447 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2018-03-06 12:48:53 66447 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2018-03-06 12:48:53 66447 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1600607
2018-03-06 12:48:53 66447 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2018-03-06 12:48:54 66447 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-03-06 12:48:54 66447 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-03-06 12:48:54 66447 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.35 started; log sequence number 1600607
2018-03-06 12:48:54 66447 [Note] RSA private key file not found: /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2018-03-06 12:48:54 66447 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2018-03-06 12:48:54 66447 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
180306 12:48:54 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Comment: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist не существует таблицы этой. вопрос в том, почему ее не существует и почему она требуется, для  этого лога этого мало, нужно больше информации, когда ошибка появилась

Comment: сожгите mamp попробуйте easyPHP, сам в свое время заканался с мампом воевать))